# Issues with self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame]

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

So I want to create an invisible boundary all around the screen with the code:

```
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
```

What it did is created an invisible top and bottom boundary correctly but the left and right boundary is a little off the screen. And with the code:

```
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
```

The simulator displayed a horizontal screen and I could see the sprite bounce off every boundary correctly. I wonder why. I want it to bounce off the screen vertically.

Thanks.

Comment: So why don't you keep `SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit`? Or is there any other issue with that? Or is your question just *why* that  is the case?

Comment: The default scale mode is "fill" which means your scene is simply not the size of the screen. How did you create the scene, what size did you use and did you create it in viewDidLoad where the view's frame is still in portrait mode?

Comment: @wumm I don't want to keep the `SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit`. I want the boundary for all four sides in portrait mode.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I didn't use the viewDidLoad but instead didMoveToView. I don't know what's the difference between the two.

Comment: didMoveToView is a SKScene method, I meant where do you run [SKScene sceneWithSize:..]? Probably in the view controller's viewDidLoad, it should be in viewWillLayoutSubviews with a proper safeguard check (see SO).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I don't run [SKScene sceneWithSize:..] anywhere. All my code is currently in didMoveToView and there's no viewDidLoad that I'm using. when I do move my code to viewDidLoad. The simulator won't load anything.

Comment: Try self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;

Comment: look in the ViewController class/files, scene creation is there, created by the Sprite Kit template

Comment: oh that might've worked. Makes sense now. Thanks!